# How to resize menu window in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: menu, resize

I have accidentally pressed some <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.. key and now my menu window (the one that opens when I click on the top left corner) is full size. Tried various settings and I'm more confused. Originally I changed the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> to be able to use it in dosbox lotus-123 for undo function, and it works there. I also set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> to resize window - and it does work for any open window except for this menu window. So the short question is: how to resize the open menu window? This is Xubuntu 18.04, I  think xfce something.